# How can I get from a function all the SymbolClass names of an external swf file?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this problem, I have several `swf files` hosted on a website, I want to create a function that returns all the `SymbolClass` names of a certain `swf file` specifying it by a parameter:

Something like this:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https: //myweb.com/assets/" + param1 + ".swf");
```

Suppose I have a `swf` called:

"`Food.swf`" and its SymbolClass are: `"Hamburger", "Potatoes", "HotDog"`, I want the function to return those names and the same way if I specify another `swf` through the parameter of that function.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first things first, you can obtain this information **ONLY** after you loaded the **SWF** in question, not before.

I have no means of testing that but should *probably* work as following:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.utils.describeType;
import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;

var aRequest:URLRequest = "Food.swf";
var aLoader:Loader = new Loader;

// Use the INIT event rather than COMPLETE.
// COMPLETE only indicates that all the bytes are loaded.
// INIT is fired AFTER the loaded SWF renders its first frame,
// and that means all the content (classes) should be available at that moment.
aLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaded);
aLoader.load(aRequest);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    // Release the event binding.
    aLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaded);
    
    // Let's see what's inside the loaded SWF.
    
    // First, let's grab the dedicated object that lists all the classes.
    var aDomain:ApplicationDomain = aLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain;
    
    // Second, let's get the list of class names.
    var aList:Vector.<String> = aDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames();
    
    trace("There are", aList.length, "(probably) classes in the");
    trace(">>>", aLoader.contentLoaderInfo.url);
    
    // Now we have them all. Let's see what's there.
    for each (var aName:String in aList)
    {
        var aClass:Class = aDomain.getDefinition(aName);
        var aDescription:XML = describeType(aClass);
        
        // Output the catch.
        trace();
        trace();
        trace(aName);
        trace();
        trace(aClass);
        trace();
        trace(aDescription.toXMLString());
    }
}
```

Some references to investigate, if the script above wouldn't work:

- aLoader.contentLoaderInfo:[LoaderInfo](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html) class
- aLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain:[ApplicationDomain](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html) class
- [describeType](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()) function

Comment: Might not work if the SWF being loaded has some class definitions on second frame or farther, like an SWF with a preloader as designed in FlashDevelop. Yet for something "flat" this should work.

Comment: @Vesper You are not incorrect. Still, we assume it all is about loading the resource libraries that author have the full control over, as well as they understand what they are doing.